# Flop counts for Cholesky, Richardson, CG

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose A is a dense symmetric positive definite 1000x1000 matrix with `κ(A)=100.` Estimate roughly how many flops are required to solve `Ax = b to ten-digit accuracy by (a) Cholesky factorization, (b) Richardson iteration with the optimal parameter α and (c) CG

I believe for (A) it would just be $~(1/3)*m^3=(1/3)*1000^3$, but I'm not sure how to go about calculating the flop count for Richardson or CG

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't tell us where you are stuck, I can only give you a hint how to start.

For the Cholesky-Decomposition, under the assumption that you don't have any round-off errors, the result will the exact solution. 
To do the decomposition for a matrix $A∈ℝ^{n×n}$ you have to do $n$ square roots, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ divisions, $\frac{n(n^2-1)}{6}$ multiplications and $\frac{n(n^2-1)}{6}$ additions. And then you also need to do a step of backwards and forwards solving.

So reducing this to $n^3$ is not fair since you can hide a lot in the $\mathcal{O(n^2)}$ term of $\frac{1}{3}n^3+\mathcal{O}(3)$.

---

The convergence rate of the CG-Method is given by:

$$\|x_k-x\|_A≤2\left(\frac{\sqrt{κ(A)}-1}{\sqrt{κ(A)}+1}\right)^k\|x_0-x\|_A.$$

.

---

For the Richardson-Iteration you need to look at the following error propagation: 
$$\|x_k-x\|=\|(I-ωA)(x_{k-1}-x)\| ≤  \|(I-ωA)\|\|(x_{k-1}-x)\|≤\|(I-ωA)\|^k\|(x_{0}-x)\|$$
So the interesting value is the spectral radius of $G_ω:=I-ωA$.
The parameter ω is chosen such that this value is optimal. With a bit of work one can get 
$$\min_{ω}ρ(G_ω) = 1-\frac{2}{κ(A)+1} $$